# Is my planned tresure-trail question allowed?

Tags: discussion

I have planned and half set up a treasure trail, made up of riddles. It takes you to a few different pages and then gives you a phrase which you can answer with.

I've just done this cos its Easter and you go on Egg hunts on Easter, so I made this for fun.

Before I post the actual question I just want to check this sort of thing is allowed and on-topic. If it is then I will post it tomorrow. Stay tuned for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a comment you said "...other questions I have asked where I have edited a clue in". You should **absolutely not** deface any other Stack Exchange questions, *even your own*; SE is meant to be a repository of high quality questions and answers, and editing your own riddles in destroys that.

Generally, puzzles should be self-contained, too; needing outside resources is allowed, but the puzzle itself should usually be entirely in the question. The more important issue is the modification of other questions, though.

(Also, all edits are public and they bump posts to the front page. The other clues were not remotely hidden because they were literally on the front page of the site.)